# No Data was found error after applying a MaxEnt classifier (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, image-classification, maxent

I am trying to redo this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/classification, using the MaxEnt classifier with my data.

Code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0ce8a254cd46d7b8d0384d9fdd2d1675

```
//*******************************************************************************************
// Set Study Area
var countries = ['HU', 'BU', 'IT', 'LO', 'AU', 'EZ'];
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB/2013').filter(ee.Filter.inList('cc', countries));
Map.addLayer(geometry.draw({color: 'ffffff', strokeWidth: 3}), {},'Study Area');
Map.centerObject(geometry, 5);

//*******************************************************************************************
// Import Data

var points = ee.FeatureCollection("users/farhatlokmen/ecoModeling/falcoCherrug");
var current245 = ee.Image("users/farhatlokmen/ecoModeling/current245").clip(geometry);

//*******************************************************************************************
// MaxEnt

var bands = ['b1', 'b5', 'b6', 'b12', 'b13', 'b14'];
var label = 'SPECIESCODE';

// Sampling
var sampleData = current245.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: points,
  properties: [label],
  scale: 500
});

// Build a classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.gmoMaxEnt(0,  0.00001, 0.00001, 0, 50)
                            .setOutputMode('PROBABILITY')
                            .train(sampleData, label, bands); // training

// Classify the image with the same bands used for training.
var classified = current245.select(bands).classify(classifier);

// Display the inputs and the results.
Map.addLayer(classified, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['black', 'red']}, 'classification');
```

Error Message: classification: Layer error: No data was found in classifier training input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message, `Error Message: classification: Layer error: No data was found in classifier training input.` usually means what it says. If you print `sampleData`, you'll see it's an empty feature collection. Going backwards from that, I see that the geometries of `points` doesn't look the way they should:

```
print(points.aggregate_array('.geo'))
```

Something might have gone wrong when you uploaded the `users/farhatlokmen/ecoModeling/falcoCherrug` asset?

Comment: **THANK YOU! ** Finally the model worked. The following are details of the reason behind this mistake (which may help other people): Originally I was facing an error because I specified a label with elements like this "AT005". After searching, I learned of how the label elements need to be pure numbers as in "5". Therefore, I opened the csv file in Excel and made the necessary changes. The latter apparently changed the encoding of the file in some way (even  though I made sure to save it as csv again). Moreover, I wasn't able to understand what happened because I did not refresh my asset list.